# Flow of automation tests with an if else logic in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In automating the passing of levels in a game, I have several user groups, which are all logging in the game with a method, that accepts the input for username and password, but receive a different number of unlocked levels, depending on the user group (each user has different levels available in the game).

In the process of testing the passing of all the levels, I want to determine during the test at the end of each level if the user has the next one unlocked, and either continue the test or finish it successfully.
I've read about if else implementations with selenium and I am currently using a method like this:

```
    public boolean isElementExisting(WebElement element){
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

and using and if logic like so in the test:

```
    if (isElementExisting(level3Button) == false) {
    driver.quit();
    }

    - rest of the tests follow here.
```

When using a `driver.quit();` the test automatically fails. The desired behavior I am searching for is for the test to pass in the if statement (what could be used instead of a `driver.quit();` method)?

I could just fit all the code for testing the further levels in separate nested if/else statements but that would be troublesome, currently looking for a more practical solution, like succeeding the test at a certain point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answer. I understand the concept of a static test, with the addition that a test should not have a "known" outcome, but more that it should have an "expected" outcome, which should be matched, in the sense that it tests something to verify its functionality.
The switch case is a valid scenario, quite frankly I don't see what happens after the assertion fails in the posted example (the test will fail as well).
The solution I implemented is to determine if the user has the next level unlocked at the end of the previous one with a method similar to this:

```
    public void isElementExistingAlternateResult(WebElement element) {
    boolean isElementFound = true;
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isElementFound = false;
    }

    if (isElementFound == true) {
        System.out.println("test is continued...");
    } else {
        Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
        System.out.println("next level not unlocked.");
    }
```

That way, only if the next available level is not found, the test will determine this real time and it will stop and pass at this exact point. Note that this is alternating the result of a otherwise failed test case with the TestNG Reporter class in:

`Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);`

The downside - this makes the test unable to test the functionality of having different amount of levels unlocked for different users, as no matter of the number of levels unlocked it will test them and pass, but that's something better of not automated.

The upside - it's super simple and works great for a test case of about 500 steps (makes only a few of them "dynamic").

Answer (score 1):

A test should be static in the sense that it should have a known outcome.
As a result, the way the test is structured and written should follow that logic.

Given what was described above, I would write a test something like this:

```
login.asUser(username,password);
// additional logic in here
assertTrue(page.userHasLevelUnlocked("level3"));
```

then the method

```
public boolean userHasLevelUnlocked(String level){
    switch(level)
        case "level3":
            if(isElementExisting(level3button){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false
            }
}
```

or something along those lines